# Comparing two strings in Python - depends on string source...?

Tags: python, string

I have the following python script:

```
import sys
import io 

str1 = 'asd'
str2 - 'asd'
if (str2.find(str1)==-1):
    print('FALSE')
else:
    print('TRUE')

#Prints "TRUE"
```

It works fine. No problem. The problem starts if I take the string, put it in a file (save it) and then read the content of the file to str1 and str2, like so:

```
import sys
import io 

fHandler = open(r'C:\dev\1.pub','r')
str1 = fHandler.read()
str2 = fHandler.read()

if (str2.find(str1)==-1):
    print('FALSE')
else:
    print('TRUE')

#Prints "FALSE"
```

Why is the behaviour different?

Thanks!

Comment: Is  `str2 - 'asd'` a copy/paste typo or a genuine part of your code?

Comment: You can't read the same file object twice like that. The `str2` will contain `''`. Did you do any debugging? Simply printing out the content of both variables should have told you the problem.

Comment: you can use `fHandler.seek(0)` before your `str2 = fHandler.read()` g back to the start of the file. Also use `with` to open your file as it will automatically get closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to call `fHandler.read()` twice, then the second one will return n empty string (or empty bytes if you read binary). `fHandler.read()` reads everything until the end and the second call will start reading at the end until the end, so it returns an empty string. Try adding `fHandler.seek(0)` beetween your function calls and it should work.